# Automatic Laravel routing for static pages

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have to maintain a site for a client, they had it made with Laravel, the most frequent requests from them are to create new static pages and the more I create them - the more I feel there are definitely better ways to implement them.
To create a static page I go to the admin panel, a menu "Static Pages", push a button "Create New" and there create an entry that goes into a database table. To make the static page show in the website I have to define it in a controller called "FrontEndController" like this:

```
public function some_page() {
  $page = StaticPages::find(1);
  return view('frontend.static_pages.some_page', compact('page'));
}

public function some_other_page() {
  $page = StaticPages::find(2);
  return view('frontend.static_pages.some_other_page', compact('page'));
}

...
```

Then define routes like this:

```
Route::get('some-page', 'FrontEndController@some_page')->name('static_page.some_page');

Route::get('some-other-page', 'FrontEndController@some_other_page')->name('static_page.some_other_page');
```

Now I always thought that you create an admin panel with a menu "Static Pages" and a button "Create New" so that you don't have to put any code manually, but seemingly the developer had other ideas...
So my question is how do you refactor a code like this so that you don't have to go through all of the repetitive process in any similar scenario and write code manually?
Btw I may need to sometimes send some generic params to different static pages and I want to keep the URLs the same as they are. Please, keep in mind that I'm not a very advanced user of Laravel or even PHP.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add extra method and router for per page manually.

I think that is a matter of unexperienced developer ,

So, You need to refactor your codes like this.

Add one router and remove others.

```
Route::get('/static/{id}','FrontendController@index');
```

On your Controller.

```
public function index($id)
{
$page = StaticPages::find($id);
$theme = $page->theme; //assume you have save your html themplate name in your table via theme column
return view('frontend.static_pages.'.$theme, compact('page'));
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't then I lose current URLs, wouldn't all of the static pages have the path `domain.com/static/1`, `domain.com/static/2` etc.? Would it work if I'd do it like this: `Route::get('{page}', 'FrontEndController@index');` and then somehow get the items by URL not the ID?

Comment: @Adam You can beneffit of Regex then redirect your old style routes to new ones.other hand you may change your routes like this Route::get('example-page-{id}', 'FrontEndController@index')

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not properly formulated, but current URL's don't have a suffix of id, these are only examples. And could you explain how could I use Regex in this situation?

Comment: @Adam You can redirect your routes like this Route::redirect('/{example_url}','static/{id}'); if your wishes is not like this then you need to save your slug in belong rows (for example example-page-01,example-page-02 and etc) in the database , then your controller request like this StaticPages::where('slug',$slug)->first();

Answer (score 0):

Save url or slug in your database

Route::get('staticpage/{pagename}', 'FrontEndController@MethodName');

$page = StaticPages::where('url',$url)->first();
return view('YourStaticPage', compact('page'));

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. Would it be a normal/conventional practice? And how would you go about it if the site was multilingual, using Laravel's built-in localization?

Comment: i already say slug or url , in multilingual slug work fine as a parameter.